# Re-Route Requests without sending Redirect to client

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-2.3

I have a pretty simple purpose

URIs of form ->`/random/*` go to `/*`. For example `/random/users` goes to `/users`.

I don't wish to use `redirect()` to solve the problem.

I have a tried a few ways but not sure about implementation -

1. Intercept the request before it reaches the router. And change the URI somehow. I am trying to Override the `onRequest` method, but unable to proceed as I don't know the implementation. (possible issue  with: should routing really be here?)
2. Have an entry in routes which is like `/random/*`, make it point to a controller method. From inside the controller call the router method again with the modified URI. Again here unable to proceed as stuck with implementation.
3. Double the routes file or put a regex in routes file. For each entry, copy it and append `/random` to it. I dont want to do this, since it makes the file difficult to manage. Last resort really.

Please help regarding how to implementation Point 1 or Point 2.
If there is any other much simpler way please help..

Comment: You can always write a custom router (which handles your requests accordingly). Or, instead of using redirect, you can just forward the call to the appropriate controller/function. I have to say though, these solutions don't look perfect... I hope someone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: @Peanut forwarding to appropriate controller/function is what I thought of in the Point 2. But here I need to get some data from the router. For example for `/random/users`, I need to figure out which controller/method is getting called for `/users`. This implementation I want.

Comment: How about: `GET /random/:controller controllers.Random.handleRandom(controller:String)`

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Random-controller and create an action which forwards the calls to the proper controllers.

Use the following route:

```
GET /random/:controller controllers.Random.handleRandom(controller:String)
```

Let the `handleRandom`-action forward the calls accordingly (with or without redirect). You can either do some reflection-magic to forward the call to other controllers, or use a if-then-else- or switch-clause.

Comment: Doesnt sound feasible to me. If there are 1million entries in routes file, will I put 1 million if else statements??(just an example). Probably the `handleRandom` should do something intelligently. I was looking for that thing.

Comment: "do some reflection-magic" means choosing the right controller-class based on the string you pass. The "if-then-else"-solution is for the case where you have 2 or 3 controller types ;-) And besides, if you have 1 million different entries, you might should consider something else than a static router file anyway.

Comment: yea that's why I said as an example. Even for 20 entries, I wont consider writing 20 if else statements :)

Comment: Then you have to resort to "java.lang.reflect"-function. Have a look at Oracles example ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html ). You get a class by it's name (as a String) and then invoke methods.